# how to check double value is empty or not

Tags: java, android, json

i'm trying to get Double value from json, i want to ask how to check double value is empty or not?

this is how i initial it
    private static

```
final String kartu_xcord = "xcord";
    private static final String kartu_ycord = "ycord";
    ouble xcord,ycord;
```

this is how i parse my json:

```
xcord = c.getDouble(kartu_xcord);
ycord = c.getDouble(kartu_ycord);
```

this is how i try to check xcord  is null or empty :

```
if (xcord.isNaN()) {
            LinlayNoMap.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            linlaymap.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

i hope someone can help me to solve my proble thank you

Comment: You can try something like that: `valueOf(xcord).isEmpty();`

Comment: `double` cannot be null

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In java `double` is a primitive type which can not be null, There is  `Double` wrapper class  in java  which can be checked as null.

Declare your coords  of type `Double` not `double` and check if `Double` value is null.

Comment: i have change to Double and make 
   if (xcord.isNaN()) {
    LinlayNoMap.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   } else {
    linlaymap.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); but it return force close

Comment: when you check by xcord.isNaN(), it will tell you if value is number or not, it will not check against null I suppose.

Comment: i check my logcar and i got an eror in this line :  if (xcord.isNaN())

Comment: so how can i check it its null or not?

Comment: you can check your Double value directly by using `if(DoubleValue==null){}` because Double is class it is not primitive type in java.

Answer (score 3):

In Java `double` cannot be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be null or empty. It's a double value. Maybe try the Double wrapper?

Comment: so i can't make condition to check it? because i want to make different view if xcord return empty value and if not

Comment: If there is no such a thing as an "empty value", how can you check for it? The Double object wrapper can be null, so maybe you can use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if your json has the key you area looking for:

```
if (c.hasDouble("my_coord")) {
  y_coord = c.getDouble("my_coord");
}
```

if y_coord is a `Double` (with capital D), you can set it to null.

```
if (c.hasDouble("my_coord")) {
  y_coord = c.getDouble("my_coord");
} else {
  y_coord = null;
}
```

This depends of course on the API you are using to read your `JSON`, the `hasDouble` method could be called something else. I recommend you give a try to `GSON`, very simple and will handle most of the parsing work for you.

Comment: so i can't make condition to check it?as you see above i want to make different view if xcord return empty value and if not

Comment: i have change to Double and make if (xcord.isNaN()) { LinlayNoMap.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); } else { linlaymap.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); but it return force close

Answer (score 1):

assume you are using JSONObject, you can do this

```
xcord = c.optDouble(kartu_xcord, Double.MIN_VALUE);

if (xcord == Double.MIN_VALUE){
  //xcord is empty
}
```

Comment: Double.MIN_VALUE could be any value that will never exists in normal data.

Answer (score 0):

doubles can never be null in Java.
You can instead use the `hasKey` method of Json to check if the item you're parsing contains the value.

```
c.hasKey("xcord")
```

Comment: so i can't make condition to check it? because i want to make different view if xcord return empty value and if not

Comment: if you stick with using a primitive double, No. Double (the wrapper class), can be nullable on the other hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can not check a primitive (double, float, long, int, char, short, byte, boolean) datatype for null.

Primitives have value always. you can only check references to Objects for null. there is a wrapper Object for each of the primitives (Double, Float, Long, Integer, ...) if you use these, then you can check for null.

```
   double c = 2.16;
   Double d = new Double(c);
   if(d != null){
     System.out.println("not null double variable");
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Double, not double.

```
Double  dValue= someVariable;

if(!dValue.isNaN())
{
 // you code here
}
```

Comment: Not a Number is a very specific value for double, and it has nothing to do with emptyness or a lack of value.